# Combining RandomizedSearchCV (or GridSearcCV) with LeaveOneGroupOut cross validation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I like using scikit's LOGO (leave one group out) as a cross validation method, in combination with learning curves. This works really nicely in most of the cases I deal with, but I am only able (efficiently) to use the two parameters that are (I believe) most critical in those cases (from experience): max features and number of estimators. Example of my code below:

```
    Fscorer = make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'micro')
    gp = training_data["GP"].values
    logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    RF_clf100 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)
    RF_clf200 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=200, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)
    RF_clf300 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=300, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)
    RF_clf400 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=400, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)
    RF_clf500 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=500, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)
    RF_clf600 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=600, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 49)

    param_name = "max_features"
    param_range = param_range = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]


    plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle('n_estimators = 100', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    _, test_scores = validation_curve(RF_clf100, X, y, cv=logo.split(X, y, groups=gp),
                                      param_name=param_name, param_range=param_range,
                                      scoring=Fscorer, n_jobs=-1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_scores_mean)
    plt.xlabel(param_name)
    plt.xlim(min(param_range), max(param_range))
    plt.ylabel("F1")
    plt.ylim(0.47, 0.57)
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()


    plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle('n_estimators = 200', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    _, test_scores = validation_curve(RF_clf200, X, y, cv=logo.split(X, y, groups=gp),
                                      param_name=param_name, param_range=param_range,
                                      scoring=Fscorer, n_jobs=-1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_scores_mean)
    plt.xlabel(param_name)
    plt.xlim(min(param_range), max(param_range))
    plt.ylabel("F1")
    plt.ylim(0.47, 0.57)
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()
    ...
    ...
```

What I would really like though is to combine the LOGO with grid search, or randomized search, for a more thorough parameter space search.

As of now my code looks like this:

```
param_dist = {"n_estimators": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
              "max_features": sp_randint(5, 30),
              "max_depth": sp_randint(2, 18),
              "criterion": ['entropy', 'gini'],
              "min_samples_leaf": sp_randint(2, 17)}

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 49)

n_iter_search = 45
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search,
                                   scoring=Fscorer, cv=8,
                                   n_jobs=-1)
random_search.fit(X, y)
```

When I replace `cv = 8` with `cv=logo.split(X, y, groups=gp)`, I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0092e11ffbf4> in <module>()
---> 35 random_search.fit(X, y)


/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y, groups)
   1183                                           self.n_iter,
   1184                                           random_state=self.random_state)
-> 1185         return self._fit(X, y, groups, sampled_params)

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, groups, parameter_iterable)
    540 
    541         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
--> 542         n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
    543         if self.verbose > 0 and isinstance(parameter_iterable, Sized):
    544             n_candidates = len(parameter_iterable)

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.pyc in get_n_splits(self, X, y, groups)
   1489             Returns the number of splitting iterations in the cross-validator.
   1490         """
-> 1491         return len(self.cv)  # Both iterables and old-cv objects support len
   1492 
   1493     def split(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Any suggestions as to (1) what is happening and, more importantly, (2) how I can make it work (combining RandomizedSearchCV with LeaveOneGroupOut)?

*** UPDATE Feb. 08 2017***

It worked using `cv=logo` with @Vivek Kumar' suggestion of `random_search.fit(X, y, wells)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pass `logo.split()` into the RandomizedSearchCV, only pass a `cv` object like `logo` into it. The RandomizedSearchCV internally calls `split()` to generate train test indices.
You can pass your `gp` groups into the `fit()` call to `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV` object.

Instead of doing this:

```
random_search.fit(X, y)
```

Do this:

```
random_search.fit(X, y, gp)
```

EDIT: you can also pass gp to the constructor of GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV in the parameter `fit_params` as a dict.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Where am I passing `cv.get_n_splits`?

Comment: @MyCarta Sorry, I was talking about `logo.split()`, not `cv.get_n_splits`. I edited my answer to remove the confusion.

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar ok that is a bit clearer. Are you also saying there is no workaround?

Comment: Yes. Unless the groups can be supplied into the constructor of LOGO, there is no way to use it directly in GridSearchCV. There are other workarounds possible for this

Comment: @MyCarta Sorry for my ignorance, but you can pass your groups to the `fit()` method of gridsearchcv or randomizedsearchcv

Comment: thanks, that is good to have in the back pocket, but the question was not really about the fitting, it was about cross validating using the groups to make the splits, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, GridSearchCV will internally call `logo.split(X, y, groups=gp)` only if you pass `gp` in the `fit()` method, and do cross-validation according to that